# Problem invalidating NSTimer in dealloc

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nstimer

Following is my code:

.h file:

```
#import "Foundation/Foundation.h"
@interface GObject:NSObject{
    NSTimer* m_Timer;
}
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSTimer* m_Timer;

- (void)Initialize;
- (void)TimerCallback:(NSTimer*)pTimer;
@end
```

.m file:

```
@implementation GObject

@synthesize m_Timer

- (void) Initialize{
    self.m_Timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5.0 
                       target:self 
                       selector: @selector(TimerCallback:) 
                       userInfo: nil 
                       repeats: YES];

}

- (void)TimerCallback:(NSTimer*)pTimer {
    //Some Code
}
- (void)dealloc {
    [m_Timer invalidate]; //--Crashes Here
    [m_Timer release];
    m_Timer = nil;
    [super dealloc];
}
@end
```

Now when the dealloc gets called, the program crashes in the line invalidating the timer. The next two lines don't even get called. I get a "EXC_BAD_ACCESS" error. Can anyone tell me why that might be happening, and what is the proper way of stopping and releasing a NSTimer member variable in a class.

Comment: Are you creating the getter/setter of the property with @synthesize?

Comment: Yes, I need to access this timer from outside my class as well. Though setter is not required.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I did some research and tests, and could figure out the answer to my own question. Ok, here it goes:

Whenever we assign `self` as target to the `NSTimer`, the timer holds a reference to our object. If the timer is repeating (or has a long time period), it would not get invalidated on its own (or will take too long to invalidate automatically, if not repeating). So, even if the object is released in the meantime, it wouldn't call the `dealloc` method, as the retain count would at least be 1. Now, I was forcibly trying to dellocate my object by calling repeated releases on it till the retain count became 0. That was my mistake.

But if you do not do that, your object will keep alive, and you will eventually have a memory leak as you lose the rest of the references to that object by various releases. The only one kept will be with the `NSTimer`. This sounds like a deadlock situation. My code crashed, because when the `delloc` tried to invalidate the `NSTimer`, it tried to release the reference that it was holding. But since I had been a smartass and reduced the retain count to 0 already, that would cause a memory exception.

To solve this, firstly I cleaned up my act and removed the code to forcibly dellocate the object. Then just before I wanted the object to be dellocated, I called the NSTimer's invalidate function. This released the target instance that the Timer had. After that, calling `release` on my object successfully dellocated it.

The bottom line is, if your object has NSTimers that repeat or do not invalidate (get over) automatically, never invalidate them in the delloc function. The delloc will not get called till the timer is holding the instance to your object. Instead have a cleanup function to invalidate the timers, before releasing the object. That is the solution that I came up with. If there is a better one out there, I most certainly want to know.

Answer (score 5):

There are a few things you should address to clean this up.

Your class declaration is a little off. If you want to inherit from NSObject, the correct syntax is:

```
@interface GObject : NSObject
```

In your implementation, you should implement `- (id)init` rather than `- (void)Initialize`. There is no instance method `- (void)Initialize`... there is a static method `+ (void)initialize`. Note the `+` and the difference in capitalization, which is significant): the `initialize` method is called once in your program before the class receives its first method.

In this case, your `Initialize` method is not being called at all (it is spelled wrong, and it is an instance method instead of a static method). Instead, you want to implement `init`, which is the designated initializer for NSObject instances:

```
- (id)init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        self.m_Timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5.0 
                   target:self 
                   selector: @selector(TimerCallback:) 
                   userInfo: nil 
                   repeats: YES];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Lastly, be sure to use the `@` symbol before the property statement:

```
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSTimer* m_Timer;
```

And don't forget to synthesize it in your implementation:

```
@implementation GObject

@synthesize m_Timer;
```

Comment: Yes, this is what's causing the crash. The timer has never been initialised because the `-Initialize` method is never called, and thus, never creates the timer. Then your dealloc method calling release on a pointer than was never initialised, this pointer could be pointing at any random object in the program, or even just garbage.

Comment: I am sorry, I should have mentioned that I was writing this code off my memory as I am not near my Mac currently. In my actual code I did all that, except the -init part.

Comment: I have corrected my code above as per your advise. As for the Initialize method, since I created it, I can call it whenever I am instantiating my object, like GObject* a = [GObject alloc]; [a Initialize]; 
I understand that this is not a best practice, but I am sure it is allowed. Please be advised that the Initialize method does get called and the Timer does get fired up. So that is not the problem. Thanks for helping me correct my post.

Comment: You still need to call init even if you call Initialize right after.

Comment: So you're sure you're calling GObject *a = [[GObject alloc] init]; then [a Initialize];?

Comment: Positive. Here is some code in my view controller's initWithCoder function:

//Some Code
GObject* lGObject = [GObject* alloc];
[lGObject Initialize];
[GSceneManager addSceneObject:lGObject]; // This is a static function of GSceneManager, that adds this object to a NSMutableArray
[lGObject release];
//Some Code

Answer (score 2):

well, i have to say that you can refer to apple developer's documentation, such as Apple's class reference. You can see from there that when invalidate: method is called, the timer's release: method will be called before invalidate: method returns.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same memory leak issue by using repeated NSTimer on one of the view controller. This view controller will not get released when it should. I finally solved this issue by moving my timer to the main application delegate code where there is no need to release the timer.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be to create a separate object that deals with the `NSTimer` callback (some `TimerController`). That object, if needed, can call the methods on your `self` controller.

Now the timer won't retain a reference to `self` and when `self` gets deallocated, `- dealloc` should be called and you can invalidate and set to nil the `TimerController` and the timer itself.